# Apply style into an element when DB flag is on

Tags: html, css, laravel

I have a couple of flags on my database, each flag represents a *state*.
For each *state*, I have an Icon, like so:

```
<div class="myClass">
 <i class="icon-flag1"></i>
 <i class="icon-flag2"></i>
 <i class="icon-flag3"></i>
</div>
```

Whenever the flag is `"on"`, I'd like to call the user's attention by changing the element color, applying a CSS.
I want to know a better/cleaner way to do it than this one:

```
@foreach($collection as $key => $obj)

   @if( $obj->flag1 )
      <i class="flag activate"></i>
   @else
      <i class="flag"></i>
   @endif

@endforeach
```

I really don't want to write this for each state I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve that by [Defining An Accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators)

Add the following code to your model like

```
public function getFlag1Attribute($value) {
    return ($value) ? '<i class="flag active"></i>' : '<i class="flag"></i>';
}
```

Then, while rendering simply do

```
@foreach($collection as $key => $obj)

   {{ $obj->flag1 }}

@endforeach
```

If you want the original value, you could retreive that by

```
$obj->getOriginal()['flag1']
```

If you want to cut down code by not writing getAttribute function for each flags, remove the getFlag1At

```
public function __get($name)
{
    if (in_array($name, ['flag1', 'flag2', 'flag3'])) {
        return ($this->getAttribute($name)) ? '<i class="flag active"></i>' : '<i class="flag"></i>';
    }

    return $this->getAttribute($name);
}
```